# regex need to do the opposite

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this regex, how do I change it so that I remove everything that is false? I tried putting `else {$(this).remove();}` but that did not have the required result. Thanks.

```
function SortFabricsFunction(){

$('#Fabric_'+ItemName).children('img').each(function () {
    var TitleIs = [this.alt];
    var TitleIs = this.alt.split(/,\s?/)
    var regex = new RegExp('^(' + [ItemGroup].join('|') + ')$');
    for(var i=0; i<TitleIs.length; i++){
        if (regex.test(TitleIs[i])) {$(this).remove();}
    }//for
});//each
}//function
```

Comment: what is ItemGroup also  the html

Comment: The requirement does not seems to be clear, can you explain it with an example

Comment: ok then what is `ItemGroup`

Comment: so you want to remove `img` with `alt` `main` if `ItemGroup` is `weave` it that it?

Comment: Yes thats it Arum. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var ItemName = '1', ItemGroup = 'main, weave';

var regexp = new RegExp('(^|,\\s*)(' + ItemGroup.split(/,\s*/).join('|') + ')($|,)', 'i');
$('#Fabric_'+ItemName).children('img').filter(function(){
    return !regexp.test($.trim(this.alt))
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XjZAN/)

In the demo it removes two `imgs` since there is two imgs with `alt` value `weave`

Comment: Arun how would you write this if: ItemGroup was an array "Main, Pique" and ItemName was an array "Main, Weave". So this would be true because both have "Main"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in that case what should happen? is it something like under `Fabric_Main` you want to display only `img` with alt `Main` and under  `Fabric_Weave` you want to display only `img` with alt `Pique`

Comment: I have edited your Fiddle and added "knit" now only one image is there. I want there to still be 3 images.
http://jsfiddle.net/WmLTc/

Comment: Or even better this one:http://jsfiddle.net/j53HM/ both can be arrays. If there is one word match then the image does not get removed. So this would remove just one image alt"knit"

Comment: Arun, do you know why this is only showing one image? http://jsfiddle.net/XjZAN/4/

Comment: @user2238083 a minor bug `var regexp = new RegExp('(^|,\\s*)(' + ItemGroup.split(/,\s*/).join('|') + ')($|,)', 'i');`